# how to read the IP of the server?

Tags: c#, windows-ce

i connect with Windows-CE to Webservice that on the Server

how i can get the server IP (before i connect to the server) ?

can i get any C# sample code ?

thanks in advance

Comment: What server?  We need more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use DNS. Specifically, look at [Dns.GetHostEntry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143998%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) which is supported by CF V2.0.

There's a basic sample at that MSDN page.